# SSRS Refresh UAT (DEV, QA) from Production

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have multiple SQL Server Reporting Services instances (Production, UAT, Development, QA, etc...).  I'd like to be able to "refresh" them from a master (Production) in the same manner as other SQL Databases.

Normally a backup from Production, restore to Development works, but with Reporting Services there seems to be an issue (user accounts, permissions, etc...) plus I'd like to keep the Data Sources pointing to Development on Development after the restore.

Have others run into this issue with SSRS and how do they resolve it?

Comment: I have never heard of anyone wanting to do this before.   Every shop I've ever worked, SSRS code was managed in Source Control.   You would never want to refresh it from a master database.

Comment: Is there a way you deploy those reports (we store them in source control as well) to many test servers (if we build a new one that means we need to create the folder structure and upload all the reports one by one and connect them up/ensure they all have the same structure) ... I was thinking a database restore would enable me to ensure they all had the same structure/version of reports/etc... but I'm open to other ideas

Comment: Source Control = Version Control.   If you want to put the version that is currently in production on your Dev server, go to that version in source control and deploy it to Dev.

Comment: Yes ... just looking for a quick deployment/refresh mechanism, rather than individual deployment and hook up of every report.

Comment: Well you can deploy the entire SSRS project all at once.   There should be versions of the entire project as well.

Comment: If you're using visual studio I believe you can control deployment through the project configuration.  TragertServerURL and TargetFolder become configurable

Comment: We are using Report Builder 3.0 and Subversion, can you point me in the direction of a tutorial or description of SSRS?  How do you account for Reports that are done outside of your control (example: CRM or other products that have reports that are deployed on install or have direct interfaces), how do you get those to different environments?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a window form application or console application to help you deploy report to any ssrs server.

You can ref to this hyperlink to see how to create folder, catalogitem or set permission

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010_methods%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a process that seems to work for us.  This enables the replication of any environment to any other environment (for testing/confirmation/etc...).

Note: it does keep all the same data, so connection string will be pointing to the original environment, but that can be resovled (see optional step)

**Backup Production Databases**

1. Backup ReportServer
2. Backup ReportServerTempDB
3. Backup Production Encryption Keys (Reporting Services Configration Manager -> Encryption Keys -> Backup)

**Restore Production Database to Target Environment**

1. Restore ReportServer
2. Restore ReportServerTempDB

**Target Report  Server Configuration**

1. Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager
2. Connect to target environment Server
3. Perform Database Update
4. Select Database
5. Click Change Database
6. Choose an existing report server database
7. Follow Prompts Selecting Restored Database
8. Perform Encryption Keys Restore
9. Select Encryption Keys
10. Click restore button
11. File Location: your-encyrption-key-file.snk
12. Password: [password entered on extraction]
13. Exit Reporting Services Configuration Manager

**Start and Stop Reporting Services Service**

1. Open SQL Server Configuration
2. Select SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
3. Right-click and select Stop
4. Right-click and select Start

**Final Data Clean-up/Processing**

1. Remove production keys: DELETE FROM Keys WHERE MachineName = '[ProductionServerName]'
2. (Optional) Remove subscriptions: DELETE FROM Subscriptions
3. (Optional) Remove connection string information: UPDATE DataSource SET ConnectionString = NULL, UserName = NULL, [Password] = NULL WHERE Extension = 'SQL'

The two optional ones are just to prevent duplicate subscriptions running and creation of reports/emails.  The connection string is a bit of a brute force to stop connections from the new environment to the old environment (then user re-key that information as is in local), this likely could be "automated" as well.